# Apex batch job is not moving

Tags: batch

I am running a batch job but it gets stuck in middle and not moving further. Has anyone faced similar thing before?

Comment: Ya this is very common issue .Batch Jobs runs in async mode and only available when we get free resources at sfdc end .

Comment: But it stuck for half an hour and not moving. Will it get resume automatically?

Comment: It will .I had same issue and it resumed automatically.Hope same here

Comment: Doga is it still stuck?

Comment: Turn debug logs on for the user the batch is running as and check if there is any movement in the logs. Also I'm guessing by stuck you mean Batches processed count isn't incrementing. Any fatal errors showing in Monitoring > Apex Jobs

Comment: I aborted it. And I checked debug logs and it shows very small log saying "Internal error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batches can be stuck and give no indication of a failure if there is a fault with the data that salesforce has not handled. For example, this can happen with objects like opportunity and opportunity line item, for sandbox refreshed from production during high user activity period. It might be worth raising a case with salesforce if this is happening quite often so that they can look into their logs and come back to you with details. This process would take a couple of days